# Python social auth account association only

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to add an 'associate google account' button to my django 1.4.8 project. I've never worked with python-social-auth before, and I'm a bit confused about only associating accounts --as opposed to authenticating against--, and how to use credentials for accessing Google Drive services.

Thanks!

A.

Comment: If your user is already logged in with a username a password you simply need to allow them to follow the same steps they would when signing up with a social account and that social account will be automatically associated with their django account

Comment: Thanks! This solved it. If you want you can add it as answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user is already logged in with a username a password you simply need to allow them to follow the same steps they would when signing up with a social account and that social account will be automatically associated with their django account